# copy file with date appended

Tags: batch-file, batch

I am writing a script that copies files to another directory. I wanted to append the date to the end of the file but when I try to use %date% I get the following:

> copy c:\mydir\file.zip "c:\temp\file-%date%.zip"
>
> The system cannot find the path specified.
>
> ```
>      0 file(s) copied.
> ```

if I remove the %date% it copies just fine

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `%date%` contains some [reserved character(s)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#naming_conventions), e.g. `/` (forward slash). As `%date%` strongly depends on user's locale settings, I'd use next *locale-independent* solution with date in [`yyyymmdd` format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387237(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
for /F "delims=" %%G in ('wmic os get LocalDateTime /value^|find "="') do set %%G
copy c:\mydir\file.zip "c:\temp\file-%LocalDateTime:~0,8%.zip"
```

**Resources** (required reading, incomplete):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%%~G`, `%~1` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (`%LocalDateTime:~0,8%"`) [Extract part of a variable (substring)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)